# Problem with wx, setup.h

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I try to compile the openphone example from the opalvoip library, but I have no success and get the following errors:

```
   /usr/include/wx/platform.h|190|error: wx/setup.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|84|error: #error "wxUSE_DYNLIB_CLASS must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|92|error: #error "wxUSE_EXCEPTIONS must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|100|error: #error "wxUSE_FILESYSTEM must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|113|error: #error "wxUSE_DYNAMIC_LOADER must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|121|error: #error "wxUSE_LOG must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|129|error: #error "wxUSE_LONGLONG must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|137|error: #error "wxUSE_MIMETYPE must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|145|error: #error "wxUSE_ON_FATAL_EXCEPTION must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|153|error: #error "wxUSE_PROTOCOL must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|195|error: #error "wxUSE_REGEX must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|203|error: #error "wxUSE_STDPATHS must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|211|error: #error "wxUSE_XML must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|219|error: #error "wxUSE_SOCKETS must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|227|error: #error "wxUSE_STREAMS must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|235|error: #error "wxUSE_STOPWATCH must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|243|error: #error "wxUSE_TEXTBUFFER must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|251|error: #error "wxUSE_TEXTFILE must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|267|error: #error "wxUSE_URL must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|285|error: #error "wxUSE_ACCEL must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|293|error: #error "wxUSE_BMPBUTTON must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|301|error: #error "wxUSE_BUTTON must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|309|error: #error "wxUSE_CALENDARCTRL must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|317|error: #error "wxUSE_CARET must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|325|error: #error "wxUSE_CHECKBOX must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|333|error: #error "wxUSE_CHECKLISTBOX must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|341|error: #error "wxUSE_CHOICE must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|349|error: #error "wxUSE_CHOICEBOOK must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|357|error: #error "wxUSE_CHOICEDLG must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|365|error: #error "wxUSE_CLIPBOARD must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|373|error: #error "wxUSE_COLOURDLG must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|381|error: #error "wxUSE_COMBOBOX must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|389|error: #error "wxUSE_DATAOBJ must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|397|error: #error "wxUSE_DATEPICKCTRL must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|405|error: #error "wxUSE_DISPLAY must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|413|error: #error "wxUSE_DOC_VIEW_ARCHITECTURE must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|421|error: #error "wxUSE_FILEDLG must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|429|error: #error "wxUSE_FONTDLG must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|437|error: #error "wxUSE_FONTMAP must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|445|error: #error "wxUSE_GAUGE must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|453|error: #error "wxUSE_GRID must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|461|error: #error "wxUSE_HELP must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|469|error: #error "wxUSE_HTML must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|477|error: #error "wxUSE_XRC must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|498|error: #error "wxUSE_ICO_CUR must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|506|error: #error "wxUSE_IFF must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|514|error: #error "wxUSE_IMAGLIST must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|522|error: #error "wxUSE_JOYSTICK must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|530|error: #error "wxUSE_LISTBOOK must be defined."|
/usr/include/wx/chkconf.h|538|error: #error "wxUSE_LISTBOX must be defined."|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build finished: 50 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I ask google about the errors and I found some hints, but they didn't help me.
I use Code::Blocks on an Ubuntu 10.04 Operating System.
Additional I use

```
`wx-config --cxxflags`
`wx-config --libs`
```

in my Compiler Options.

Answer (score 3):

On a second look, I think you're trying to use an ANSI compiled wx with UNICODE Code::Blocks project. So: Get UNICODE WX

Comment: Thx, I'am builded the wxGTK-2.8.11 with Unicode and It works.